# Views created by addView method change their backgrounds togheter when pressed

Tags: android, listview

The code below is about making custom list view, the adapter create for each item a view "list_view_child" and in the getView method there's a for loop composed 3 repetition, in this for loop we add 3 new views "list_item" on "list_items_container" using method addView(View v), the "list_item" has a selector to change the background of "list_item" view and here is the problem. **if I click on one of these views their backgrounds change together.**

Display these images to understand the problem well :

Pressed_false : http://i44.tinypic.com/2jfaqzb.png

Pressed_true (if "Item 2 & View : 1" Or "Item 2 & View : 2" Or "Item 2 & View : 3" pressed) : http://i42.tinypic.com/2l97ayw.png

list_view_child XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d2d2d2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:color="#ff0000"
        android:text="Test" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_items_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item XML Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:color="#ffff00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_true" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_false" />
</selector>
```

pressed_true :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

pressed_false :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
</shape>
```

List View Adapter Class :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private HashMap<String, String> data;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;

        HashMap<String, String> datapos = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datapos = data.get(position);

        LinearLayout listitemcontainer = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_item_container);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            View listitem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            TextView itemtitle = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemtitle.setText("Item : " + position + " & View : " + i);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams listitemparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            listitemparams.setMargins(0, 15, 22, 0);
            listitem.setLayoutParams(listitemparams);

            listitemcontainer.addView(listitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your views don't have click listener, by default they will take the selection state of their parent. To prevent that, you can use this property on your list_item:

android:duplicateParentState="false"

Comment: I have set click listeners to "list_item" views and the problem GONE :) thanks